# NuGet Pack .nuspec file returns "The replacement token 'version' has no value."

Tags: nuget, token, nuget-package, author, nuspec

This is the error I got while trying to pack a project in Visual Studio 2013:

```
PM> NuGet Pack C:\ITVizion\RTVizion\ITVizion.RTVizion.Service\ITVizion.RTVizion.Service.nuspec -Prop Configuration=Release
Attempting to build package from 'ITVizion.RTVizion.Service.nuspec'.
NuGet : The replacement token 'version' has no value.
At line:1 char:1
+ NuGet Pack C:\ITVizion\RTVizion\ITVizion.RTVizion.Service\ITVizion.RTVizion.Serv ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The replacement...' has no value.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem:

[image]

Make sure you fill your project [Assembly Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ts8eta17%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page.

You can access it right clicking your project in Visual Studio `Solution Explorer`. Select `Application tab => Assembly Information...` button.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has a similar error message, and finds that the error message does not go away even if the information is indeed specified in the Assembly Information, I figured out a fix. I don't see this documented in anyone else's answers, and note that this in fact contradicts what the docs say.

Once you've created **SomeProject.nuspec** with the various `$id$`, `$author$`, etc replacement tokens plus any any custom replacement values, the docs instruct you to then place SomeProject.nuspec** into the same directory as **SomeProject.csproj**, and run

```
nuget.exe pack SomeProject.csproj -Build
```

This did not work for me - I got errors about replacement tokens with no value.

However, what ***did work*** for me is to call

```
nuget.exe pack -Build
```

in the same directory as the nuspec and csproj files, ***without*** specifying which csproj or nuspec file to use. This successfully created the nupkg file with the replacement tokens appropriately substituted based on what I specified in the nuspec!

Hopefully this information will be useful to someone else out there!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in NuGet 3.3. I get the following error: NuGet.CommandLineException: Please specify a nuspec or project file to use.

More information here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1985